# Converting dates into time series based on difference from date in other dataframe in r

Tags: r, date, data.table, bigdata, lubridate

EDITED: to clarify that there may be multiple `A04` per `id`

I need to get all the registrations from the previous 6 months which is specific to each case individually.

I would like to set an artificial timeline. So all cases `id` have their own timeline. The starting point being the first row with `x=A=04`, then counting the days back/forward and selecting based on days. NOTE: this is a huge dataset and there can be multiple `x=A04` per `id`.

My dataset looks something like this:

```
    id x   date
 1: 12 D95 2015-06-19
 2: 12 A04 2015-08-15
 3: 12 A01 2015-03-16
 4: 12 A04 2015-12-20
 5: 10 K20 2017-02-20
 6: 10 B10 2017-09-01
 7: 10 A04 2017-12-11
 8: 10 A84 2017-10-11
```

**Data:** (EDITED according to suggestion jay.sf)

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    x = c("D95", "A04", "A01", "A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "A84"
    ), date = structure(c(16605, 16510, 16455, 17217, 17410, 
    17511, 17450, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a separate dataset `df_s` with single rowed `id` and the earliest `date` of `x=A04`. Thought this would help, but now I am stuck...

Example of seperate dataset `df_s`:

```
    id date    
 1: 12 2015-08-15 
 2: 10 2017-12-11
```

**Data** (Added according to suggestion by jay.sf)

```
df_s <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 10L), date = structure(c(16789, 17511
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

This would be my desired new dataset (days not precisely calculated):

```
    id x   date       days.since.first.A04
 1: 12 D95 2015-06-19 -98
 2: 12 A04 2015-08-15 0
 3: 12 A01 2015-03-16 -170
 4: 12 A04 2015-12-20 127
 5: 10 K20 2018-02-20 70
 6: 10 B10 2017-09-01 -101
 7: 10 A04 2017-12-11 0
 8: 10 A84 2017-10-11 -60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(DT, key=c("id","date"))[, date := as.IDate(date)]
DT[, days.since.first.A04 := unique(DT[x=="A04"], by="id")[.SD, on=.(id), i.date - x.date]]
```

output:

```
   id   x       date days.since.first.A04
1: 10 B10 2017-09-01                 -101
2: 10 A84 2017-10-11                  -61
3: 10 A04 2017-12-11                    0
4: 10 K20 2018-02-20                   71
5: 12 A01 2015-03-16                 -279
6: 12 D95 2015-06-19                 -184
7: 12 F85 2015-08-15                 -127
8: 12 A04 2015-12-20                    0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("id x   date
12 D95 2015-06-19
12 F85 2015-08-15
12 A01 2015-03-16
12 A04 2015-12-20
10 K20 2018-02-20
10 B10 2017-09-01
10 A04 2017-12-11
10 A84 2017-10-11")
```

Comment: there seems to be some entries in the date column in your dataset that is not of the %Y-%m-%d format. can you try `head(sort(DT$date))` and `tail(sort(DT$date))`?

Comment: Oh there might be multiple A04 for the same ID? Then you might need to filter for the first

Comment: Yes, indeed, filter for the first. That's why I made a separate file `df_s` with first `A04` per `id`.

Comment: Added some code to sort and then take the first per id. But  not in front of computer to test or update the output

Comment: This `data.table` solution solves the issue with the size of the dataset I had with the `match` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `match` and simple subtraction.

```
df <- transform(df, days.since=df$date - df_s$date[match(df$id, df_s$id)])
#   id   x       date days.since
# 1 12 D95 2015-06-19  -184 days
# 2 12 F85 2015-03-16  -279 days
# 3 12 A01 2015-01-20  -334 days
# 4 12 A04 2017-02-20   428 days
# 5 10 K20 2017-09-01  -101 days
# 6 10 B10 2017-12-11     0 days
# 7 10 A04 2017-10-11   -61 days
# 8 10 A84       <NA>    NA days
```

**Edit:** If your date variable isn't yet in `"Date"` format use `as.Date`.

```
df <- transform(df, days.since=as.Date(df$date) - as.Date(df_s$date[match(df$id, df_s$id)]))
```

---

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
    x = c("D95", "F85", "A01", "A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "A84"
    ), date = structure(c(16605, 16510, 16455, 17217, 17410, 
    17511, 17450, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")

df_s <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 10L), date = structure(c(16789, 17511
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, that was a typo. You do not need to convert `as.numeric`, though;  `as.Date` is sufficient. See edit.

Comment: Had to divide my large dataset (>40mil rows) into 3 seperate data.tables before R ran it, but it worked.